# Can't get My Documents path in Silverlight 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-oob, elevated-privileges

For some reason this line of code...

```
var dirInfo = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

...returns an empty string on my dev machine.

I'm running OOB and with elevated trust on Win7.

I don't honestly know quite where to start on this.  Can anyone shed any light?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I can't repro -- I have a "bare" silverlight project, with just the one line you have, and once I enable out of browser and elevated trust, it works.  Now, without elevated trust, the exception that gets throw includes an empty string as the path -- maybe you aren't really getting elevated?

Comment: Thanks for trying.  As I suspected,.. this was environmental. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joy of joys...

The problem was down to my working from home on a machine which uses roaming profiles!  Should've guessed that really.

The fix was simple enough.

RegEdit -> HKCU -> Software -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Current Version -> Explorer -> User Shell Folders -> Personal was pointing to a remote (unavailable) path.  Just changed this to a local path and all worked well.